# Google datastore : backups schedule

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, gcloud

I'm trying to create a schedule backups for my database on datastore.
I'm trying to use this command via gcloud

```
gcloud alpha firestore backups schedules create \
--database='DATABASE_ID' \
--recurrence=weekly \
--retention=RETENTION_PERIOD \
--day-of-week=DAY
```

But its not work on datastore.
Is there any command that creates schedules backups for datastore?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have found the solution:

Here is an example:

```
gcloud alpha firestore backups schedules create --project=<project-id> --database="<database-id>" --recurrence=weekly --retention=14w --day-of-week=SUN
```

Comment: To echo what changed.  RETENTION_PERIOD needs to be changed to a value (e.g. 8w for 8 weeks), and DAY needs to be replaced with a value (e.g. WED for Wednesday).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

> Is there any command that creates scheduled backups for datastore?

I don’t think there is any direct command to create scheduled backups for Datastore.I couldn't find any such command at [datastore cli documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/datastore). However you can raise a feature request at [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers). To work around this you can use Cloud Functions and Cloud Scheduler by following below steps.

#### Steps :

1. **[Create a Cloud Function that creates a backup of your Datastore database.](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/schedule-export#create_a_cloud_function_and_job)**

   - You can find the python cloud function code snippet in the above shared docs.
2. **[Configure the Cloud Function to have necessary permissions to create backups.](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/schedule-export#configure_access_permissions)**

   - You will have to give the following permissions to the default service account

     - ***Cloud Datastore Import Export Admin***
     - ***Owner*** or ***Storage Admin*** role on the bucket
3. **[Create a Cloud Scheduler job that triggers the Cloud Function on a weekly schedule.](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/schedule-export#create_a_job)**

   - Enter Frequency as weekly frequency using [unix-cron format](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/configuring/cron-job-schedules)

When the above setup is done the cloud function will listen for any messages sent to the configured pub/sub topic. cloud scheduler we will send the payload as a message to that pub/sub topic on the basis of scheduled frequency(for ex: weekly) which we have set in the above cloud scheduler step.